# Rule triggers twice

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

Simple rule to send account email after updating a [commerce license](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license).

[image]

Export

```
{ "rules_membership_activation_email_notification_v2" : {
    "LABEL" : "Membership activation email notification v2",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "WEIGHT" : "-10",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "commerce_license" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_license_update" : [] },
    "DO" : [
      { "user_send_account_email" : {
          "account" : [ "commerce-license:owner" ],
          "email_type" : "status_activated"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Debug

```
Rules debug information:
" Reacting on event After updating an existing commerce license.

    0 ms Reacting on event After updating an existing commerce license.
    12.037 ms Evaluating conditions of rule Membership activation email notification v2. [edit]
    12.046 ms AND evaluated to TRUE.
    " Rule Membership activation email notification v2 fires. [edit]
        0 ms Rule Membership activation email notification v2 fires.
        0.207 ms Evaluating the action Send account e-mail. [edit]
        55.557 ms Rule Membership activation email notification v2 has fired.
    67.623 ms Finished reacting on event After updating an existing commerce license.

" Reacting on event After updating an existing commerce license.

    0 ms Reacting on event After updating an existing commerce license.
    0.111 ms Evaluating conditions of rule Membership activation email notification v2. [edit]
    0.122 ms AND evaluated to TRUE.
    " Rule Membership activation email notification v2 fires. [edit]
        0 ms Rule Membership activation email notification v2 fires.
        0.113 ms Evaluating the action Send account e-mail. [edit]
        28.104 ms Rule Membership activation email notification v2 has fired.
    28.243 ms Finished reacting on event After updating an existing commerce license.
```

As you can see it triggers twice and sends two duplicate emails, should send one.

Tried with other random actions, they all trigger twice.

Got another rule that sends email on new license creation after checkout and it is not duplicate, it only triggers once as it should.

Comment: If the Rule is being run twice, it's because you've "updated an existing commerce license" twice. Which implies there is other code modifying the license.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was solved with this https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license/issues/2205923#comment-8525711

> This works just like for any other entity type, you check that commerce-license:status is not equal to commerce-license:original:status (confirming that it has just changed), and then in the next condition you check that commerce-license:status is expired.

Except 'original' now is 'unchanged'.

Don't know how or why, but it works.